# Pandas- Fill nans up until first non NULL value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have a dataframe like

```
A    B    C
1    nan  nan
2    nan  5
3    3    nan
4    nan  nan
```

How do I only fill the NULLs (with 0) for each series up until the first non NULL value, leading to

```
A    B    C
1    0    0
2    0    5
3    3    nan
4    nan  nan
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bit of a trick using `pandas.DataFrame.ffill` with `notna` and `where`:

```
df.where(df.ffill().notna(), 0)
```

Or using `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`:

```
df.interpolate('zero', fill_value=0, limit_direction='backward')
```

Output:

```
   A    B    C
0  1  0.0  0.0
1  2  0.0  5.0
2  3  3.0  NaN
3  4  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Awesome!! Didn't know about interpolate. Very helpful

Answer (score 5):

This would be done using `where` or `mask`.

```
df.mask(df.notna().cumsum().eq(0), 0)
# or,
df.where(df.notna().cumsum().ne(0), 0)

   A    B    C
0  1  0.0  0.0
1  2  0.0  5.0
2  3  3.0  NaN
3  4  NaN  NaN
```

Many ways to skin a cat here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since 0 + nan is nan this works:

```
xf = df.fillna(0) + df.bfill()*0
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Answers above. Alternately, if you want to do it for a specific column:

```
df[columnName][:df[columnName].first_valid_index()].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```