# Replace NaN by 0, starting after first non-nan value per row

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a pandas DataFrame in which I need to populate the `NaN` values by `0` starting from the first non-nan numeric value in each row.

It is close to this post, but doing the operation per row and not per column: [How to populate NaN by 0, starting after first non-nan value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818456/how-to-populate-nan-by-0-starting-after-first-non-nan-value)

Example df

```
   name day1 day2 day3 day4
0 Alice  NaN  5.0  NaN  6.0
1   Bob  NaN  NaN  3.0  2.0
2 Carol  3.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Desired output

```
   name day1 day2 day3 day4
0 Alice  NaN  5.0  0.0  6.0
1   Bob  NaN  NaN  3.0  2.0
2 Carol  3.0  0.0  0.0  4.0
```

I tried to modify the method from linked question, but also some workaround [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654338/pandas-fill-nans-up-until-first-non-null-value?rq=3), unfortunately didn't managed to get through.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why the value in column day3 row 0 is replaced

Comment: @TiTo That's just the way I want it: replace NaN by 0 if a non-NaN numeric value has already been found on the same row (reading from left to right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can craft a boolean mask with [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)+[`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='day'))
# or
# cols = ['day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4']

df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(0).where(df[cols].notna().cummax(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    name  day1  day2  day3  day4
0  Alice   NaN   5.0   0.0   6.0
1    Bob   NaN   NaN   3.0   2.0
2  Carol   3.0   0.0   0.0   4.0
```

Intermediate:

```
# df[cols].notna().cummax(axis=1)

    day1   day2  day3  day4
0  False   True  True  True
1  False  False  True  True
2   True   True  True  True
```

Or adapting the linked approach be used with rows and ignoring the non-day column (which I don't like as much as the above):

```
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].mask(df[cols].ffill(axis=1).notna(), 0), axis=1)
```